# 配列の中にある要素が配列の場合、特定の要素(配列)があるかどうかを判定したい

Tags: javascript

#### やりたいこと

配列の中に要素として配列が複数存在していて、
指定した要素(配列)があるかどうかをtrue, falseで返り値として取得したい。

#### 分からないこと

includesやsomeを使用して、試しにtrueが返ってくると思っていたコードを書いたのですが、
falseが返ってきており、うまく検索できていない理由がわかりません。

```js
// someを使用
const winning_set = [
  ['グー', 'チョキ'],
  ['チョキ', 'パー'],
  ['パー', 'グー']
];

const result = ['グー', 'チョキ'];

const i = winning_set.some(
  set => set === result
);
console.log(i);
// => false



// includesを使用
const winning_set = [
  ['グー', 'チョキ'],
  ['チョキ', 'パー'],
  ['パー', 'グー']
];

const result = ['グー', 'チョキ'];

const i = winning_set.includes(result);
console.log(i);
// => false
```

falseになる原因がわかるかご存知でしたら、教えていただけると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

配列同士を直接比較する方法はないようです。
配列を文字列に変換してから比較すると「やりたいこと」に近いことはできます。

```
const winning_set = [
  ['グー', 'チョキ'],
  ['チョキ', 'パー'],
  ['パー', 'グー']
];

const result = ['グー', 'チョキ'];

const i = winning_set.some(
  item => item.toString() == result.toString()
);
console.log(i);
// => true
```

区切り記号(,)と同じ値が含まれる場合、誤認する場合がありますので工夫が必要です。
汎用的な配列比較は難しいです。JSONに変換し、JSONのライブラリを使用するのも一案かと思います。
次の例では`[',', ',,']`と`[',,', ',']`を同一視してしまいます。

```
const winning_set = [
  [',', ',,'],
  ['グー', 'チョキ'],
  ['チョキ', 'パー'],
  ['パー', 'グー']
];

const result = [',,', ','];

const i = winning_set.some(
  item => item.toString() == result.toString()
);
console.log(i);  //trueと誤認
```

Comment: こちら今確認しました。ご丁寧に回答ありがとうございます！